# Problems while reformating a nested list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have the following `lis` of tuples after making a lot of reformating:

```
[[(('A', 'X'), ('43,23', 'Y'), ('wepowe', 'd'))]]
```

How can I reformat into:

```
'A', '43,23', 'wepowe'
```

I tried to:

```
[' '.join(map(str,lis[0][0])) for x in lis]
```

and

```
[' '.join(map(str,lis[0][:1])) for x in lis]
```

and

```
' '.join(map(str, lis))
```

However, I do not get the desired format. Which is the easist way of reformating tuples and lists like the above?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
my_list = [(('A', 'X'), ('43,23', 'Y'), ('wepowe', 'd'))]
result = [item[0] for item in my_list[0]]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> result
['A', '43,23', 'wepowe']
```

Comment: My problem was actually entering to the first parethesis, is that done with `item[0]`?

Comment: It is done by `my_list[0]`, inside your list you have one element, to access it you need to use `my_list[0]`, then for each item, to access the first sub-item you should use `item[0]`

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
>>> my_list = [(('A', 'X'), ('43,23', 'Y'), ('wepowe', 'd'))]
>>> new_list , _ = zip(*my_list[0])
#              ^ replace this with some variable in case you also want the
#                elements at `1`st index of each tuple
```

Value hold by `new_list` will be:

```
>>> new_list
('A', '43,23', 'wepowe')
```

Comment: Thanks!, I liked this solution, could you explain a little bit what is happening and if this is the most efficient?.

Comment: Check [zip document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). You will get the idea on what it does. Also, you may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180861/zip-as-a-list-comprehension) helpful. In my solution `zip(*my_list[0])`, `*` is used to unpack the list and then zip is performed on the unpacked list

Comment: Actually it worked 1 minute ago... I am getting this: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: You must have changed the structure of your input list OR, you would not be calling the `zip` function as I did :)

Answer (score 2):

Before you write any list comprehensions lets iterate the list using 2 `for` loops, like:

```
tups = [(('A', 'X'), ('43,23', 'Y'), ('wepowe', 'd'))]

for item in tups:
    for j in item:
        print j[0]
```

Now if you were to see we get the first element of each tuple we are looking for, we can convert it to a list comprehension expression like so:

```
' '.join(str(j[0]) for item in tups for j in item)
```